# Magento 2 - Moving navigation make issue in responsive

Tags: magento2

I'm moving navigation menu in Header container, I'm using the below code in default.xml of my theme:

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header.container" after="logo"/>
```

This works fine, but when I view this in mobile/responsive view, the menu doesn't show the correct Navigation items,instead it's displaying Header Links (Sign up, Sign In).

Without moving in the Header, the responsive menu is correct what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
One more, same is the case with the header.links (Sign In, Sign up). I moved them inside header wrapper but now they are removed in responsive menu.

Comment: What xml you have written for top links? please share

Comment: <move element="header.links" destination="auth-block" before="head-info-text"/> 
I used the above line in default.xml to move the header link to Header Content area, in a div 'auth-block', this works fine, but in responsive view, these links doesn't appear in the Menu slider.

Comment: Use this code: <move element="top.links" destination="auth-block" before="head-info-text"/>